# Magento 1.9 Hide tax on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I want to hide the tax from the checkout. [image]
For some reason I cannot do that from Admin > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings. I found the phtml file that displays the tax, and this is how is dispayed:`<?php echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); ?>`

and this is the renderTotals() function:`/**
     * Render totals html for specific totals area (footer, body)
     *
     * @param   null|string $area
     * @param   int $colspan
     * @return  string
     */
    public function renderTotals($area = null, $colspan = 1)
    {
        $html = '';
        foreach($this->getTotals() as $total) {
            if ($total->getArea() != $area && $area != -1) {
                continue;
            }
            $html .= $this->renderTotal($total, $area, $colspan);
        }
        return $html;
    }`

My question is how to override this function, so it ingores the tax?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the line

```
echo $this->renderTotals('taxes', $this->getColspan());
```

on phtml `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`

but first copy this file to your custom template to avoid erasing core template